# Should this code be made testable?

Tags: python, testing

My code looks roughly like

```
40 def send_pubkey( s: socket ) -> None:                                           
41     '''Transmit own public key unencrypted.'''                                  
42     _, pub = crypto.read_keypair()                                              
43     s.sendall(pub.save_pkcs1())
```

This is extremely difficult to test as it involves network operations. However adding another level of abstraction between this layer and OS sockets goes against `import this*`. Any silver bullet out there?

<sub>* - Simple is better than complex.</sub>

Comment: Please define "goes against `import this`"

Comment: [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)?

Comment: @PhilipKendall [import this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deciphering-pythons-import-this-891f182c6b91)

Comment: Thanks @candied_orange It still remains entirely unclear to me what the OP's actual objection is, particularly given "practicality beats purity". I think/hope we all know you can't actually define software engineering best practices in 20, or even 20,000 lines. OP: please clarify.

Comment: @PhilipKendall my guess was going to be the flat over nested thing but you're right, the OP has left me guessing.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Vorac has edited to define his `import this` concern.

Comment: @candied_orange "In programming there is only one problem not solvable by introducing another abstraction layer: the problem of too many layers."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to make this code unit testable is not by mocking it. It's to give it a functional core.

```py
def extract_pubkey( crypto ) -> bytes:
    _, pub = crypto.read_keypair() 
    return pub.save_pkcs1()
```

That is unit testable. It simplifies `send_pubkey` down to a one liner, if not out of existence. Yes it leaves the sending code not under unit test but that's as should be. Unit tests are about internal behavior. Not integration with the outside world.

Answer (score 3):

I would say no.

In these cases it's better to create a test environment (docker?) and actually send packets, integration rather than unit testing.

A unit test with a mocked network layer is going to be testing the mock to a large extent, and just wont pick up on lots of common networking errors.

Comment: +1 but sorry for changing the accepted answer. I got down to it just now and realized implementing a whole new layer(containers) is so much over my head. Thanks again, I'll keep Your wisdom in mind!